# Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : unique() applies only to vectors by converting daywise data (daily) to monthly data using R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, quanteda

```
# On Linke

topic1<-c("Polizei", "Deutschland")

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

tokens_Linke_topic1<-tokens_keep(tokens_Linke, pattern = topic1)
dfm_Linke=dfm(tokens_Linke_topic1)

dfm_Linke_topic1<-dfm_group(dfm_Linke, groups = date)
```

1. I have a quite large dfm of tweets from a political party (Linke). Im trying to convert daywise data (daily) to monthly data and getting the error described above. Could someone help? Thanks!

Comment: We would need more details on what `date` is. Can you supply a minimally reproducible example? But I suspect that the best solution is to use `date` to create a new (document) variable called `month`, and then aggregate your dfm based on this new month variable.

Comment: Please provide a sample data set, for example running `dput(head(dfm_Linke, 10))`. It will be easier to reproduce the issue.